# Universal TypeConverter for PropertyGrid property

Tags: c#, propertygrid, typeconverter

I have a problem. I'm trying to add properties to propertyGrid control, with its correct type converter.
I'm using reflection, so actually i know what exactly type of value came only when i'm initializing my propertyGrid.

Something like that:

```
public SettingsProperty(SettingsFieldValue value, SettingsFieldInfo info)
{
  Value = value;
  Info = info;
  _defaultValue = Info.DefaultValue;

  Name = Info.Label;
  Description = Info.Description;
  PropertyName = Info.FieldName;
  TypeName = Info.FieldType.ToString();
  CurrentValue = GetValueAsString(Value);
  DefaultValue = GetValueAsString(_defaultValue);
}
```

So. It can be bool, int, double, array, dictionary or complex object with its nested properties.
Is there any way to create converter for that property at runtime?

Like, if came object, it became expandableTypeConverter. If boolean - boolean converter etc.

Thanks for any help or thoughts.